# I'm get a report of error ') expected' in django

Tags: html, django

I have a django website, and in my html I get these in my visual studio editor, I don't know why. Basically everything works, but I have some problem with flex, sometimes it doesn't work, also I don't know if it is connected.

Any idea what is this?

[image]

This is home.html

```
<section class="welcome_area clearfix" id="home" style="background-image: url({% static 'img/bg-img/welcome-bg.png' %})">
```

Same in base.html

```
<div class="mosh-breadcumb-area" style="background-image: url({% static 'img/core-img/breadcumb.png' %})">
```

**EDIT**

After changing based on sunil ghimire answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the double and single quotes Django is misinterpreting them(strings ends at wrong place), because you have to use 3 nested strings.

your 3 strings are :
1 : `"background-image: url()"`.

2 : `'{% static %}'`.

3 : `"/img/core-img/breadcrumb.png"`

how django is interpreting them (starting and ending quotes) :

1 : `"background-image: url('{% static "`.

2 : `img/core-img/breadcumb.png`.

3 : `" %}')";>`.

What you can do :

use Absolute url instead of {% static %}

Answer (score 0):

**home.html**

```
<section class="welcome_area clearfix" id="home" style="background-image: url('{% static "img/bg-img/welcome-bg.png" %}')";>
```

**base.html**

```
<div class="mosh-breadcumb-area" style="background-image: url('{% static "img/core-img/breadcumb.png" %}')";>
```

Comment: I got new error, I updated question.

Comment: Now, it doesn't load an image.

Comment: check once... may be this could help.. also make sure you load static on top of the page and image path is correct